# quickbooks sdk slow adding customers QB Enterprise 13

Tags: quickbooks

QBFC11 and QBFC12, VB.Net 2008, QB ES 13
We have seen this a couple of times in different applications at different clients.

When our program adds a customer it can take up to 8 minutes each.

One customer seen this fell back to a prior QB version and the problem immediately dissappeared.

Is there a QB patch that fixes this?

Recommendations???

Comment: Is that for ALL customers? Or just customers with a parent customer?

Comment: Please raise a support ticket - https://developer.intuit.com/Support/Incident

Comment: I am not sure of the first client several months ago but the last client was definitely a job.

Comment: We cannot open an incident because we cannot create it here and do not have access to the client's QB or system and we have an issue with the way Inituit's incidents work.